# Crear diccionario a partir de elementos de una lista de tuplas

Tags: python, diccionarios, nlp, tuplas

Estoy intentando crear un diccionario que dado un pre-pedido (una lista con tuplas) que contiene comida y cantidad, sea capaz de extraer el valor de la comida y la cantidad de cada pre-pedido, y que si no hubiese una cantidad predefinida para una comida, se le asigne "1" como cantidad.

Teniendo en cuenta el PRE_PEDIDO de abajo (código), el diccionario debería devolver una lista:
({'Comida':"un",'Cantidad':"vino"},{'Comida':"pollo",'Cantidad':1})

Sin embargo me devuelve:
{'Comida/Bebida': 'pollo', 'Cantidad': 'un'} --> la segunda comida ("pollo") está sustituyendo a la primera ("vino").

Os dejo el código hasta ahora:

```
PRE_PEDIDO = [('un', 'di0ms0', 'B-cantidad'), ('vino', 'ncms000', 'B-comida'), ('pollo', 'sps00', 'B-comida')]

cantidad = 1
alimento = ""

for t in PRE_PEDIDO:
    if t[2] == 'B-comida':
        alimento = t[0]
    elif t[2] == 'B-cantidad':
        cantidad = t[0]

pedido = dict()
pedido['Comida/Bebida']=alimento
pedido['Cantidad']=cantidad
print(pedido)
```

Gracias de antemano,

Saludos

Comment: En el pedido, ¿cómo asocias comida con cantidad?¿van siempre una cantidad seguida de una comida?¿cómo sabes que una comida no tiene una cantidad asociada?

Comment: No los estoy asociando y ahí puede estar el error, en español cuando se pide comida, se suele indicar primero la cantidad y luego la comida. El tema sería crear un programa que itere por el pedido, y que cuando encuentre una comida, coja la cantidad justo delante; y si no existe cantidad, que ponga 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que el pedido será una secuencia de "cantidad" seguido de "comida", o sólo "comida" si la cantidad es exactamente 1.

Lo más sencillo de entender sería tomar la lista `PRE_PEDIDO` como iterador e ir pillando elementos de dos en dos o de uno en uno según sea un par "cantidad-comida" o sólo un elemento "comida":

```py
PRE_PEDIDO = [
    ('un', 'di0ms0', 'B-cantidad'),
    ('vino', 'ncms000', 'B-comida'),
    ('pollo', 'sps00', 'B-comida')
]

it = iter(PRE_PEDIDO)

pedido = []
for (x, _, tipo) in it:
    if tipo == "B-cantidad":
        cantidad = x
        (comida, _, _) = next(it)  # pillamos el siguiente, de tipo "B-comida"
    else:
        cantidad = 1
        comida = x
    
    pedido.append({"Comida/Bebida": comida, "Cantidad": cantidad})

print(pedido)
```

Comment: Eso mismo es lo que buscaba! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para que te muestre todo como vos querés, tenés que identar hasta la linea del print.

```
for t in PRE_PEDIDO:
      if t[2] == 'B-comida':
         alimento = t[0]
      elif t[2] == 'B-cantidad':
        cantidad = t[0]
      pedido = dict()
      pedido['Comida/Bebida']=alimento
      pedido['Cantidad']=cantidad
      print(pedido)
```

Haciéndolo así te muestra:

```
{'Comida/Bebida': '', 'Cantidad': 'un'}
{'Comida/Bebida': 'vino', 'Cantidad': 'un'}
{'Comida/Bebida': 'pollo', 'Cantidad': 'un'}
```

No sé si eso es lo que querés ver.

Comment: Hola Lucas, gracias por tu propuesta, en parte soluciona el problema, pero no del todo, para que fuese perfecto el output tendría que ser este:                              {'Comida/Bebida': 'vino', 'Cantidad': 'un'}
{'Comida/Bebida': 'pollo', 'Cantidad': 1}